# How to read a line large remote file given file pointer in Python 3?

Tags: python, file-handling, file-pointer

I have a remote file and its url. Id like to read a line from it, using the pointer to the first character of the line, without downloading it.
Had the file been local, I'd use `file.seek(pointer)` to set the file pointer and use `file.readline()`.

How do I do it when the file is remote?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide a **[mcve]**.

Comment: Show us what you have tried?